# Matplotlib background won't match vscode theme

Tags: matplotlib, visual-studio-code, jupyter

When I create a matplotlib chart in my jupyter notebook in vscode, it gives the whole cell a white background.  I've tried putting

```
"import matplotlib.pyplot as plt",
"plt.style.use('dark_background')"
```

in my settings file to run as startup commands and that makes it gives the plot a black background, but it still doesn't match my vscode theme.  Does anyone know how to make them match seamlessly?  transparent chart background mabye?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The white background is actually on purpose so that it matches what Jupyter would show. It's from reading the 'needs_background' element of the matplotlib output.

The background unfortunately will always be either white or black based on the 'needs_background' element. (As you found with your style of 'dark_background')

The code for that is here:
https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-notebook-renderers/blob/91210f63be0fcca92d7ea9125b7e9445a423b0a4/src/client/render.tsx#L70

You can enter a request for the jupyter extension to change that color here:
https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter/issues

Answer (score 0):

You can plot your chart in a PyQt5 window.

I am not sure if this solves your problem, but it's a way to make the chart transparent. I hope it's helpful:

You need to import PyQt5 (pip3 install PyQt5).

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore
```

The code to create the transparent window is inserted after defining your figure:

```
window = plt.gcf().canvas.manager.window # used to get your figure
window.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.WA_NoSystemBackground, True)
window.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground, True)
window.setStyleSheet("background:transparent")
```

Finally show the window with plot.show():

```
plt.show()
```