# Matplotlib background matches vscode theme on dark mode and can't see axis

Tags: python, matplotlib, visual-studio-code

I just got a new PC and downloaded visual studio code. I'm trying to run the exact same plots as the code I had on my other PC (just `plt.plot(losses)`) but now `matplotlib` seems to have a dark background instead of white:

[image]

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68559726/matplotlib-background-wont-match-vscode-theme) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61567100/vscode-default-dark-theme-doesnt-automatically-defaults-the-matplotlib-style) that had opposite problems.
To clarify, I'm asking how to change the matplotlib background plots to white (note that in my other machine I didn't have to hard code any matplotlib background information so I think it's a visual studio problem, but couldn't figure it out)

Comment: are you asking how to change the VS Code theme?

Comment: Apologies for the confusion, please see my clarification

Comment: https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/introductory/customizing.html

Comment: VS Code inject a color scheme onto matplotlib when using notebooks. The question is not "How can I change my matplotlib color", but "How can I stop VS code from interfering with my matplotlib colors", which none of the current answers touches.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Difficult to be sure since I cannot reproduce your problem.

Two things to try (both presume that you import matplotlib using `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt`):

1. if you use `plt.figure`, add `facecolor='white'` parameter. Or try to run `fig.set_facecolor('white')` (`fig` here is the variable that stored the figure which facecolor you are changing. If you don't have any, use `plt.gcf().set_facecolor('white')` once the figure is created; `gcf()` returns current figure, see this [doc](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.gcf.html)).
2. Try to change `plt.style.context` as in [this matplotlib example](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/style_sheets/plot_solarizedlight2.html).

Comment: Yea, the `style` worked. It's just weird because I didn't need to do anything using the exact same code in my other machine. So I think it's definitely a visual studio code issue. But alas, this will do. Thanks

Answer (score 7):

You could also set the `runtime configuration` (`rcParams`) to change it for the entire sacript/notebook ([documentation](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/introductory/customizing.html))

```
import matplotlib as mpl
mpl.rcParams['figure.facecolor'] = 'white'
```

Answer (score 3):

[image: Jupyter: Theme Matplotlib Plots setting image]

Changing this setting did the trick for me

Comment: I think this is the actual answer.

Answer (score 1):

in the settings-extensions-python-experiments: Opt Out Form-

there is and option that says:

jupyter.themeMatplotlibPlots": false,

if true mark it false this worked for me